# next line in jython

Tags: jython

count_record=file.readline()
     count_prev=count_record[:-1] ,

i used this to read the previous line and it worked but now when i am using

`count_next=count_record[:+1]` i am not able to read the next line , is there is way to do so read the next time .

Thanks for your help

Comment: I suspect it isn't really doing what is believed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with jython to know what type of data structure `count_record` is here, or how it ought to be used.

However, I do know that in any case, it is the call to `file.readline()` that is getting the next line.

If you want to use the next line, you will need to call readline again. So, for a quick example, your code would look something like this:

```
count_record=file.readline()  
...  
 //use count_record here  
...  
count_record=file.readline()  
...  
  // We now have the second line, use it here  
...
```